# Filling in School reports (v from a spreadsheet file in which all grades are kept

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I'm trying to migrate my excel files to the google spreadsheets but I have trouble with the following. In my excel design what I did was keep grades in a single file. From this file I made a connection with a report file in which all the grades automatically appeared.

When I tried to do this in Spreadsheets it appears to be very difficult to make cross references between files.

Basically what I want is this:
1. File with all grades for my students (this already works)
2. Some kind of way to create a report in another file in which the grades that belong to one student appear.
3. When there is a second report or third report make it possible to add the grades to the first report that was created.

I'm not a crack at using macro's, but is it possible to create something that allowes me to do this?

In Excel I created a report file for every student and then from that file I made a reference to the grade file. This was maybe not the most efficient way to to do it but it worked. Now I want to migrate to spreadsheets I really would I like to know if there are easier ways to create the report file.

I have converted a gradelist for report 1 and one report from a student so you have an idea of what i'm talking about. The grades of column B in the grade files correspond with the B report file with the report 1,2 and 3.

[grade file report 1](https://docs.google.com/a/daltonschooloegstgeest.nl/spreadsheets/d/156Xz8wlkSLZezsvWVNqol-gXLvc5TzuANDQIC-VTYns/edit#gid=963347925)

[Report of student column B](https://docs.google.com/a/daltonschooloegstgeest.nl/spreadsheets/d/1pbKxrabhnjVoX24kQg2Sx-DaVfi8vEkTlyEpqun1J_0/edit#gid=1279972911)

I hope you can help me out!

Thank you in advance!

Rik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in spreadsheet function called =importRange(), no apps script needed.

The basics are =IMPORTRANGE(SpreadsheetID, RangeToImportInA1Notation)

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340